# Registration Override - FosUser Bundle ( CSRF token is invalid)

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

When i use the standard logic, it works, register without any problem.

```
<form action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" class="fos_user_registration_register">


        {{ form_widget(form) }}

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}" />
    </div>
</form>
```

however when i manually override the fields, it looks like its registering, however, it doesn't register, error being thrown is  CSRF token is invalid. Do i have to add anything else to make this code work?

```
<form action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" class="fos_user_registration_register">


        {{ form_widget(form.username) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.email) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.Position) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.Country) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.notification) }}

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

I found what the problem is, just needed to add

```
{{ form_rest(form) }}
```

> This renders all fields that have not yet been rendered for the given
>   form. It's a good idea to always have this somewhere inside your form
>   as it'll render hidden fields for you and make any fields you forgot
>   to render more obvious (since it'll render the field for you).

For more on `form_rest()` see the symfony docs [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html)